# An efficient way to update dictionary in MongoDB?

Tags: python, performance, pymongo

I have this MongoDb schema:

```
tags:{
"image_uid":"",
"faces": [
    {
        "image_uid":"",
        "age_real":""
    }
]}
```

witch I update with a dictionary

```
feedbacks = [{
                 'face_uid': '02d42dee-3b66-11e2-b12e-e0cb4e12150c',
                 'age': 23
             },
             {
                 'face_uid': '02d42dee-3b66-11e2-b12e-e0cb4e12150d',
                 'age': 23
             }]
```

in this way:

```
 for feedback in feedbacks:
    tags.update(
        {'image_uid': image_uid, 'faces.face_uid': feedback['face_uid']},
        {"$set": {'faces.$.age_real': feedback['age']}}, w=1
    )
```

There is a more efficient way instead of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently MongoDB offers no support for updating multiple array elements at once. However, instead of performing several updates in sequence, you might choose to use the [Update if Current](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/) pattern, or something similar, to update your document locally and then replace it on the DB.

Also, check the original [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243), where you can find a couple work-arounds in the comments.